# Migrating from Android Pay to Google Payment API

Tags: android, android-pay

TL;DR: Can I process a transaction using a `PaymentDataRequest` built using `WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_ESTIMATED` as the `TransactionInfo`'s "TotalPriceStatus"?

### Full Issue Description

I have an app that currently has AndroidPay integrated as a payment method, and I want to migrate this to use the new [Google Payment API](https://developers.google.com/payments/overview).

Users can purchase things that are shipped to them, and since shipping costs can change based on location, I can't calculate the final cost of the order until I get the user's shipping address from the `MaskedWallet` (AndroidPay) or `PaymentData` (Google Payment). When using AndroidPay, the user is shown a bottom-sheet dialog when I request the `MaskedWallet`, then I can calculate the order total, and then request the `FullWallet` with an exact amount to charge the user.

If I follow the same basic pattern with Google Payment, I request a `PaymentData` like so:

```
PaymentDataRequest.Builder request = PaymentDataRequest.newBuilder()
        .setTransactionInfo(TransactionInfo.newBuilder()
            .setTotalPriceStatus(WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_ESTIMATED)
            .setTotalPrice("123")
            .setCurrencyCode("USD")
            .build())
        .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_CARD)
        .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKENIZED_CARD)
        .setPhoneNumberRequired(true)
        .setEmailRequired(true)
        .setShippingAddressRequired(true)
        .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(getTokenizationParameters())
        .setCardRequirements(getCardRequirements());
```

where `getTokenizationParameters()` and `getCardRequirements()` are locally defined helper methods. After I make this request, a dialog is shown to the user that confirms their address and credit card (just like requesting the `MaskedWallet` for AndroidPay), then I show a confirmation UI of my own that shows a breakdown in the price. When the user clicks to confirm the purchase and place the order, I'm creating another `PaymentDataRequest`, but this time using `WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_FINAL` in the `TransactionInfo` because I know know exactly how much the customer will be charged, like so:

```
PaymentDataRequest.Builder request = PaymentDataRequest.newBuilder()
        .setTransactionInfo(TransactionInfo.newBuilder()
            .setTotalPriceStatus(WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_FINAL)
            .setTotalPrice("133.5")
            .setCurrencyCode("USD")
            .build())
        .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_CARD)
        .addAllowedPaymentMethod(WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKENIZED_CARD)
        .setPhoneNumberRequired(true)
        .setEmailRequired(true)
        .setUiRequired(false)
        .setShippingAddressRequired(true)
        .setPaymentMethodTokenizationParameters(getTokenizationParameters())
        .setCardRequirements(getCardRequirements());
```

I'm doing this second request in part because this mirrors the process used in Android Pay with a `FullWallet`, but the UX is terrible because of this second dialog.

Do I have to create a `PaymentDataRequest` using `WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_FINAL` to get a `PaymentData` that I can use to charge the user, or can I use `WalletConstants.TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_ESTIMATED` and use that `PaymentData` to charge the user, even though the exact dollar amount the user is charged may be different from the amount I created the request with?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly pointed out, unlike the old Android Pay API which had `loadMaskedWallet` and `loadFullWallet` that were supposed to be called in different parts of the flow, the Google Pay API only has a single `loadPaymentData` call which can be, in this sense, considered a combination of the two (i.e. calling `loadFullWallet` immediately after `loadMaskedWallet`).

This means that there's no need to make the second `PaymentDataRequest` - since your final price is not known when you request the payment credentials from Google, `TOTAL_PRICE_STATUS_ESTIMATED` is the correct approach. Once you've received the payment credentials successfully, there's no need to make any further calls to the API.

Keep in mind that Google does not process transactions, so you would still need to provide your payment processor / gateway with the correct final amount.